# i need to change text of marker on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi dear team and community of stack overflow, i search in developers google and i don't have answers to my problem, i create a route with google maps and fine works! but i when i push the marker this shows me the information of the direction and but i don't need its dangerous because this map can be  see for the companies to search people for work and i don't have idea for how to hide or change tis information for example "Here is house of xxx" than "Av Avenida 98373, zap, jal, mx".

Im sorry for my bad english ! this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 80%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_GMAPS&sensor=true&language=es"></script>
    <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

var rendererOptions = {
  map: map,
  suppressMarkers : false,
  suppressInfoWindow: false
}

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

}




  var request = {
      origin:'Av guadalupe 5765 zapopan jalisco',
      destination:'Av Guadalupe 1010 zapopan jalisco',
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";
      document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";



    }
  });








google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

<body>    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
  <span id="distance"></span>
    <span id="duration"></span>
</html>
  <script language="javascript"> 
calcRoute(); 
showSteps();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `suppressInfoWindows`-option of the `DirectionsRenderer` to `true`.
This will avoid the automatic InfoWindows.

```
var rendererOptions = {
  map: map,
  suppressMarkers : false,
  suppressInfoWindows: true
}
```

For a custom text you must use a custom InfoWindow-Instance (set it via the infoWindow-option of the `DirectionsRenderer`). Observe 
the `domready`-event of this infoWindow and set the desired content.